# Pass certain parameters from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax, object

I have an array of objects. if i do a console.log, i can see these array of objects.

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object,Object]
[0-4]
0:Object
    Name: Nikhil
    User_ID:123 
    admin:true
    read:false
    write:false
1:Object
    Name:andy
    User_ID:124
    admin:false
    read:true
    write:false
2:Object
    Name:Nik
    User_ID:125
    admin:false
    read:false
    write:true
3:Object
    Name:ranea
    User_ID:126
    admin:false
    read:false
    write:true 
4:Object
    Name:isha
    User_ID:127
    admin:false
    read:true
    write:false
```

Now, if i do JSON.stringify, i get this output.

```
[{"Name":"Nikhil","User_ID":"123","admin":true,"read":false,"write":false},
{"Name":"andy","User_ID":"124","admin":false,"read":true,"write":false},
{"Name":"Nik","User_ID":"125","admin":false,"read":false,"write":true},         
{"Name":"ranea","User_ID":"126","admin":false,"read":false,"write":true},
{"Name":"isha","User_ID":"127","admin":false,"read":true,"write":false}]
```

Instead of doing stringify to all the parameters, I want to only do it to few. For e.g. I don't want to pass Name. I only want to pass User_ID since it is unique, and admin,read,write properties.

How can i create a new array of objects using loadash and then stringify the result. My final output after JSON.stringify should be like this

```
[{"User_ID":"123","admin":true,"read":false,"write":false},
{"User_ID":"124","admin":false,"read":true,"write":false},
{"User_ID":"125","admin":false,"read":false,"write":true},         
{"User_ID":"126","admin":false,"read":false,"write":true},
{"User_ID":"127","admin":false,"read":true,"write":false}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [_.pick](https://lodash.com/docs#pick) it should be:

```
 var newArr = _.map(oldArray,
  function(item) {
    return _.pick(item, ['User_ID', 'admin', 'read', 'write']);
  });
```

Comment: Hi @theodore- i am getting undefined for all the values. can you have a look at my console output which is mentioned at the start of question.

Comment: Hello @anjaligupte checkout my edited answer. I had forgotten the `return` statement.

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of the [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function.

```
var obj = [ { "Name": "Christophe", "Age": 42, "foo": "bar" }, { "Name": "Blah", "Age": 42, "foo": "foo2" }]
var filtered = obj.map(function (element) {
    return {
        "Name": element.Name
    }
});
```

After that, `filtered` contains your objects with only the keys you want to keep, and you can `JSON.stringify` it.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(filtered));
// [ {"Name": "Christophe"}, {"Name": "Blah"} ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this little function to return
the new Array.

```js
var arr = [{
  Name: "Nikhil",
  User_ID: "123",
  admin: "true",
  read: "false",
  write: "false"
}, {
  Name: "andy",
  User_ID: "124",
  admin: "false",
  read: "true",
  write: "false"
}];

function returnArr(array) {
  var arrNew = arr;
  for (let in arrNew) {
    delete arrNew[let].Name;
  }
  return JSON.stringify(arrNew);
}

document.write(returnArr(arr)); // or console.log(returnArr(arr))
```